# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.png" when using turtle graphics

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I wrote this code on a linux laptop (Ubuntu), but now, when I try to run it on a mac I get the error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.png"
```

this happens when trying to set the image as the background during my graphics **init** function.

```
    def __init__(self):
    self.window = turtle.Screen()
    self.window.setup(724, 724)
    self.window.bgpic("background.png")
    self.window.tracer(0, 0)
```

[Here is the image that it is using](https://github.com/willybh11/chessGame/blob/master/background.png)

Comment: I tested your image with `bgpic()` on Python 2.7.12 on Linux Mint 18.2 based on Ubuntu 16 and it works. `turtle` is built on `tkinter` which supports only `gif` as default, so it can be problem in `turtle` too. There is special class in module `PIL/pillow` to use `png` (and other format) with `tkinter`. I already have `pillow` installed and I can't check if `bgpic` has problem without `pillow`. You can try to install `pillow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.bgpic
, the background pic must be a GIF. PNG is not supported. But you can convert the PNG to a GIF on the fly using either PIL/Pillow (Python Imaging Library) or NumPy.